# Conservation of flux in scattering problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, probability, time-evolution, unitarity

Consider a localised potential which becomes 0 after some distance $a$.

[image]

So, we are considering a wave coming from infinity along z direction, so for $r>>a$, $\psi_{incoming}=e^{ikz}$
Now for scattered wave for $r>>a$, we have to solve
$\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}=-k^2u$
where $R(r)=\frac{u(r)}{r}$
So, we get $R(r)=\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}$
So,    $\psi_{scattered}=f(\theta)\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}$

Now the incoming probability current,
$\phi_{in}=\frac{h}{m}Im(\psi_{incoming}^*\nabla\psi_{incoming})$
$\phi_{in}=\frac{h}{m}Im(e^{-ikz}ike^{ikz})$
$\phi_{in}=\frac{\hbar k}{m}$

The outgoing probability current,
$\phi_{out}=\frac{h}{m}Im(\psi_{scattered}^*\nabla\psi_{scattered})$
$\phi_{out}=\frac{h}{m}|f(\theta)|^2Im\Big(\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\big(\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\big)\Big)$
$\phi_{out}=\frac{hk}{mr}|f(\theta)|^2$

But as we are dealing with the stationary states, so the incoming probability current should be equal to the outgoing probability current.
So, $\phi_{in}=\phi_{out}$
$\implies\frac{hk}{m}=\frac{hk}{mr}|f(\theta)|^2$
So, $\boxed{|f(\theta)|^2=r}$

Is the final result correct? It does not seem correct to me that the norm of $f(\theta)$ shoukd be dependent on $r$.

Comment: (a) You might want to double check your calculation of $\phi_{out}$. (b) Given $\psi_{in}=e^{i k x}$ and $\phi_{in}=\phi_{out}$, what does dimensional analysis tell you about $f(\theta)$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. Yes I have made mistake in $\phi_{out}$. In the gradient I should also include $\frac{\partial}{r\partial\theta}$. So we will get $|f(\theta)|^2\frac{k}{r^2}+Im(\frac{f^*}{r^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta})=k$. (b) From dimensional analysis, we can say that the dimension of $f(\theta)$ is same as that of length.